# Should these expressions evaluate differently?

Tags: python, if-statement

I was somewhat confused until I found the bug in my code. I had to change

```
a.matched_images.count #True when variable is 0
```

to

```
a.matched_images.count > 0 #False when variable is 0
```

Since I quickly wanted to know whether an object had any images, the first code will appear like the photo has images since the expression evaluates to `True` when the meaning really is false ("no images" / 0 images)

Did I understand this correctly and can you please answer or comment if these expressions should evaluate to different values.

Comment: If a.matched_images.count is the int 0, then it should evaluate to False.  Could you insert a print type(a.matched_images.count) command right before the line? Possibly it's a method?

Comment: An integer expression is generally `True` if it is non-zero, it is `False` otherwise.  Assuming `a.matched_images.count` is an integer, both would have different results if the value was a negative number.

Comment: The number of count is built-in to the environment (google app eninge + django) and I believe it's a django variable of the number of matches of a collection when there is a referenceproperty between 2 models. And yes, it's likely a method. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I was also thinking about the difference between the statements `if isHuman` and `if isHuman == True` where it might not be obvious what the first evaluates to if the variable was just set to None or not initiated. Therefore I think it can be best to use defaults more and defaults that are semantic (a boolean that can have three values should be avoided)

Comment: @Nicklas R: "it's likely a method"?? "I don't know whether it's '0' or 0"?? What's stopping you from finding out what it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> bool(0)
False
```

So.. no, if it were an int that wouldn't matter. Please do some tracing, print out what `count` actually is.

Comment: It could be this problem `>>> bool('0')` and i'll look more carefully what's going on. I've been rather certain that the value is 0 but I don't know whether it's `'0'` or `0`.

Answer (score 3):

What is the nature of `count`?  If it's a basic Python number, then `if count` is the same as `if count != 0`.  On the other hand, if `count` is a custom class then it needs to implement either `__nonzero__` or `__len__` for Python 2.x, or `__bool__` or `__len__` for Python 3.x. If those methods are not defined, then every instance of that class is considered `True`.

Comment: django template variable for a number of a collection a referenced variables appearing in the GAE manual as `The value of the property is a Query for all entities that reference the entity` and in the template context it's new in version 1.2 that there are tests for <,> and == using template tags. So the nature is a template variable.

Comment: @Ethan: and what if count is **LESS THAN** zero?

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing what `count` is, it's hard to answer, but [this excerpt](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) may be of use to you:.

> The following values are considered false:
>
> - None
> - False
> - zero of any numeric type, for example, 0, 0L, 0.0, 0j.
> - any empty sequence, for example, '', (), [].
> - any empty mapping, for example, {}.
> - instances of user-defined classes, if the class defines a
>     `__nonzero__()` or `__len__()` method, when that method returns the
>     integer zero or bool value False. [1]
>
> **All other values are considered true — so objects of many types are
>   always true.**

Comment: `__nonzero__` in Python 2.x becomes `__bool__` in Python 3.x